# What is causing these errors?

Tags: perl, initialization, fasta

Use of uninitialized value `$Xentr4` in concatenation (.) or string at Convert1.pl at line 6

I am getting below error:

> Error opening  no such file or directory at Convert1.pl line 6"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# This script takes a user specified interleaved fasta input file $ARGV[0] and converts it to a sequential fasta file
use strict;

my $Xentr4=$ARGV[0];
open(IN, "<$Xentr4") || die ("Error opening $Xentr4 $!");

my $line = <IN>; 
print $line;

while ($line = <IN>)
{
        chomp $line;
        if ($line=~m/^>/) { 
                print "\n",$line,"\n"; 
               }
        else { 
                print $line; 
               }
}
```

Comment: Great, solved! Next question - what is the best way to output the result to file (instead of just printing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is probably coming because you are not passing any command line argument. And since you are initializing `$Xentr4` with first command line argument, it will remain un-initialized in the absence of any argument.

You need to pass your file name as command line argument to your script.

---

Apart from that, you should use `3-arg` open:

```
open (IN, "<", $Xentr4) or die ("Error opening $Xentr4 $!");
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing lines 5 and 6 to the following worked:

my $Xentr4="Xentr4.fasta"; 
open(IN, "<", "$Xentr4") || die ("Error opening $Xentr4 $!");

Comment: @user2081026. Yeah, now you just gave your file name directly. That's fine.

Comment: So here's another stupid question:

What's a good way to output to file (instead of just printing) the result? Could be same file or a new one.

Comment: @user2081026. AFAIK, you can give a file handle to print to print to the file like this: `print OUT $line;`. Where `OUT` is the file handle for output file.

Comment: Using the three-argument-version of `open` is better, but even better would be using the three-argument-version of `open` with lexical filehandles. `open my $fh , '<' , $Xentr4 or die "Error opening $Xentr4 $!";`

Comment: @dgw. Oh! right. Forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$Xentr4` may be `undef` or `filepath` may not be correct.

In order to avoid such issues, you can add checks.

```
if ( (defined $Xentr4) && (-e $Xentr4) ) {
    open(IN, "<$Xentr4") || die ("Error opening $Xentr4 $!");
} else {
     print "Check the Argument passed.\n";
}
```